Optimal strategy for a free throw game
My friend recently showed me a game designed to help drill free throws in basketball. I'm interested in calculating an optimal strategy but I've gotten stuck.
Rules of the game
Players, taking turns in a fixed order, attempt 2 free throws. Every made free throw increments the points on the board, a global counter of how many free throws have been consecutively made prior. When a free throw is missed, a player adds all the points on the board to their individual score and the points on the board reset to 0. Each player starts with 0 points and exits the game upon reaching $z$ points. Last one in the game wins.
Problem
Given these rules, when should a player intentionally miss? For each attempt, a player can either shoot (S) to make the basket with probability p or intentionally miss (M). It never makes sense to shoot then miss intentionally; missing twice is strictly better. But it may make sense to intentionally miss the first basket if there are $k$ points on the board to avoid making that first basket, then taking $k+1$ points on a miss.
Attempt 1
If a player only cares about minimizing their own score, then the choice is fairly straighforward. Let $X_S$ and $X_M$ represent the number of points taken on their turn (which starts with $k$ points on the board) using a shoot-shoot and miss-shoot strategy respectively.
$$E[X_M] = k$$
$$E[X_S] = (1-p)k + p(1-p)(k+1)$$
$$ E[X_S] \geq E[X_M] \to (1-p)k + p(1-p)(k+1)-k \geq 0 \to p \geq \frac{1}{k+1} $$
Here's a simple result: the player should attempt to shoot as long as their free throw percentage is better than $\frac{1}{k+1}$. However, this analysis is incomplete. Note this rule suggests a player should always miss their first free throw when there's no points on the board unless they shoot perfectly. There is no value on racking up points on the board for other players to take when they miss.
Attempt 2
The game has end conditions so maybe it's possible to work backward with dynamic programming. There are 3 parts of the game state: the current player $i$, the number of points on the board $k$, and the player scores $\hat{s}$.Let $$A(i, k, \hat{s}) be the cost at that game state. Here, a player can either miss-miss or miss-shoot or shoot-shoot.
$$A(i, k, \hat{s}) = min(A_{MM}, A_{MS}, A_{SS})$$
$$A_{MM} = A(i + 1 \bmod n, 0, \hat{s} + ke_i)$$
$$A_{MS} = (1-p_i)A_{MM} + p_iA(i + 1 \bmod n, 1, \hat{s} + ke_i)$$
$$A_{SS} = (1-p_i)A_{MS} + p_i(1-p_i)A(i + 1 \bmod n, 0, \hat{s} + (k+1)e_i) + p_i^2A(i + 1 \bmod n, k+2, \hat{s})$$
But this doesn't really work. It's unclear how to set the boundary conditions. For one, the state space is technically infinite since the points on the board can be unbounded though the probability of that approaches 0. Second, since getting over $z$ points loses the game, one thought is to have $A() = \infty$ for all states where at least one point total is above $z$. But that would make all the states equal to infinity.
Thoughts
I'm a bit stumped on how to approach this problem. Reducing down to just 2 players might make it more tractable but I haven't gotten all that much farther. Any help with this would be appreciated!

A quick read suggests that the optimal strategy depends on the other players' abilities as well as their possible strategies, with analysis depending on whether you know how good they are when they are trying to succeed.

I think it makes sense to assume that all the p_i are known to all players who have the same choices (miss-miss, miss-shoot, shoot-miss, shoot-shoot)
